# django url with two slugs coflict

Tags: django, django-urls

i have in my urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)/$', page, name='page'),
url(r'^(?P<slug1>.+)/(?P<slug2>.+)/$', subpage, name='subpage'),
```

page and subpage are two functions in two different models.

and in my app1/views.py

```
def page(request, slug):
    try :
       #some code
    except myModel.DoesNotExist:
       return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>not found</h1>')
```

and imy app2/views.py

```
def page(request, slug1, slug2):
    try :
       #some code
    except myModel.DoesNotExist:
       return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>not found</h1>')
```

the problem is i dont get the subpage!

if i change the urls to

```
url(r'^AAAA(?P<slug>.+)/$', page, name='page'),
url(r'^BBBB(?P<slug1>.+)/(?P<slug2>.+)/$', subpage, name='subpage'),
```

everything goes well !

how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `. +` in your regular expressions. It will match all characters, including slashes. Usually, you would use `[-\w]+`, which matches letters a-z and A-Z, digits 0-9, hyphens and underscores.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', page, name='page'),
url(r'^(?P<slug1>[-\w]) /(?P<slug2>[-\w]+)/$', subpage, name='subpage'),
```